# how to resize and rotate image using mouse using c# windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to resize and rotate image on my canvas . I implemented this for touch devices using gestures which works fine, but now i want to do this for pc so that it can be resized and rotate with mouse .I know that pointer events will be used but I dont know how to do this.
Need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use manipulation events for moving. For scaling and rotating you can use mouse scroll events (with `PointerWheelChanged` event) and modifiers like Ctrl, Alt (with `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown/Up`), but really there should be some control points that show up when you use a mouse:

```
this.PointerEntered += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        this.isUsingMouse = true;
        this.UpdateVisualState(true);
    }
    else
    {
        this.isUsingMouse = false;
        this.UpdateVisualState(true);
    }
};
```

`UpdateVisualState` would call in to `VisualStateManager.GoToVisualState()` and a visual state you define would display the manipulation adorners that you'd drag with mouse to resize/rotate.

Comment: yes that we have corners when we use any other image editor , arrows to resize and rotate.

Comment: Would you explain a little what this code does and UpdateVisualState(); method?

Comment: The code is for detecting whether a mouse has been used. `UpdateVisualState()` is typically the name of the method you write for updating visual states as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574437/focusable-winrt-usercontrol-with-image-background/23575053#23575053). Visual states are typically designed in Blend, but basically in most typical case it's a group of logical view states defined in XAML by their names and `Storyboards` that animate transitions to these respective states.

Comment: thanks for concept of adorners , understood the logic behind it.